# Saving PDF's generated with flying-saucer directly to /resources or any other folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I'am pretty new to java and spring MVC. I now can successfully create PDF Files with thymeleaf and flying-saucer like in this example: [How to generate pdf Report using thymeleaf as template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320438/how-to-generate-pdf-report-using-thymeleaf-as-template-engine)

In this example, files are stored in the local temp folder java.io.tempdir. My question is: How can i save these generated PDF's to my /resources directory or any other directory in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example "out" is the path to file to be stored ,

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getFile()`

will give resource folder location add your filename ,

pass

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getFile()+"/"+"yourfilename.ext"`

as "out"

Comment: Accept if it helped you.

Comment: So i applied these changes and used getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getFile()+"myPDF.pdf" as the "out" in the method call. The application does run without error and confirmes, that it saved the PDF, but i can't find it anywhere in my project explorer.
If i print the out statement i get something like this="*Projectname*/WEB-INF/classes//myPDF.pdf"

Comment: WEB-INF/classes/ is the location of the resources folder at run time @JulienKnepper you can see the file in target folder if your running from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

just specify the full path in your system properties. It works and make sure you have the folders in place.

```
System.getProperty("C://Documents//myfolder");
```